# Is there a formula in excel to find if a two letters cell in row1 exist in row2 and 3?

Tags: excel, match, letter

I have a sheet in excel with three rows and three columns. I am looking for a formula in excel to find if the letters in first row exists in two other rows (each cell has two letters). For example this is my data:

```
    A |  B |  C
------+----+---
1. MN | MM | HO
2. NN | KM | JJ
3. LM | MM | KO
```

I want to have a formula to return number of cells that are not match for each row, in column D and highlight the cells in row 2 and/or three that not exists in row one.

For example in my data: The string in C1 is HO and we have O in C3 but we don't have H in C2. But for two other columns (A & B), one letter of row A1 (MN) is in row A2 (NN) and the other one in A3 (LM), so row 2 column C should highlighted in red and number of mismatch should be 1 in row2 column D.

Comparisons are made individually in each column and the sum of the cells that highlighted in red is written in column D of the corresponding row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Row 1 is equal to "HO"? What do you mean?

Comment: @Dominique sorry for making you confused.I edited the text.